# Join two different size cells in the same struct

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I want to put together 2 cells of different sizes in the same `struct`. For example:

```
a = {'one', 'two', 'three'};
b = {'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'};

struct("setA", a, "setB", b);
```

Whenever I try to do this, MATLAB throws the following error:

> error: struct: dimensions of parameter 2 do not match those of parameter 4

According to the error message the problem is the dimensions of the cells. Furthermore, if I remove one element from cell `b` the process finishes without errors:

```
a = {'one', 'two', 'three'};
b = {'four', 'five', 'six'};

struct("setA", a, "setB", b);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the cells in *another* cell to create a *scalar* `struct` containing cells in it's fields.

```
struct('setA', {a}, 'setB', {b})

%   setA: {'one'  'two'  'three'}
%   setB: {'four'  'five'  'six'  'seven'}
```

By default, `struct` assumes that a cell means that you want a multi-element `struct` where each cell element will belong to a different `struct`. It uses the dimensions of these cells to determine the size of the resulting `struct`. In your case, the two cell arrays (`a` and `b`) are different sizes so it gets confused.

By wrapping each of them inside of another cell, MATLAB will create a scalar struct containing your cell arrays as you expect.